# Integrating an oscillating (interpolated) function with GSL and python

Tags: python, integration, interpolation, numerical-methods, gsl

I am trying to integrate a highly oscillatory data with the function *qawo* from the [GSL Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) and [pygsl](http://pygsl.sourceforge.net/) in python. Since I am dealing with data I though that a interpolated function could work, but GSL gives me an incorrect result **!!**. Let me explain by taking the function **Sin(x)/(1+x²)** as an example.

The following code works fine:

```
import pygsl
from  pygsl import integrate

def f1(x,y):
    return 1./(1 + x**2)
sys = integrate.gsl_function(f1, None)

w = integrate.workspace(100)
cyclew = integrate.workspace(1000000)

table = integrate.qawo_table(1, 10000, integrate.SINE, 100)
flag, result, error = integrate.qawo(sys, 0, 1e-8, 1e-8, 100, w, table)
```

gives **0.626761** as it should. But if we simulated data points using the above function...

```
xarr = np.linspace(0,1e15,1e30)  
yarr = np.sin(xarr)/(1.+xarr**2)

interp = interpol.interp1d(xarr,yarr)

def fgsl(x,y):
    return interp(x)

syst = integrate.gsl_function(fgsl, None)

w = integrate.workspace(1000)
cyclew = integrate.workspace(100000000)

table = integrate.qawo_table(1, 1e10, integrate.SINE, 100)

flag, result, error = integrate.qawo(syst, 0, 1e-15, 1e-15, 100, w, table)
```

which gives a completely wrong result: **4.2426e-21**

Moreover, if we integrated *yarr* with the *simps* function:

```
import scipy.integrate as ints
res = ints.simps(yarr,xarr)
```

gives a pretty good approximation: **0.64676099**.

Just assume that I can't use the Simpson's rule. Does anyone knows how can I use an interpolation function with gsl? or how can I change the code in order to do the integration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @Vinicius Miranda, but you'r answers doesn't help. Indeed I am trying to integrate a function in the range [a,inf] and both functions _qawo_ and _qawf_ can perfectly deal with that without false convergence as I pointed out in the first part. Now,1) the 1e15 in xarr I put it just to emphasize I need to integrate in a big range of data, as I say this is an example. 2) I put the dx = 1e-15 because otherwise I obtain an error of the order of the result, but that doesn't matter because the result is wrong. If I change the value of dx keeps giving a wrong result, that is not the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The numbers in your example don't quite make sense and they will break any adaptive scheme. Let me explain why.

You are trying to integrate an oscillatory function with period 2*Pi from 0 to 10^10! No adaptive scheme will be able to "see" the oscillatory behavior on that interval and they will converge w/ the wrong result (false convergence)! Remember that adaptive schemes use a top-down approach. They apply some rule on the entire interval, and then they divide that interval in two and apply the same rule in each subdivision. After a few cycles (usually 4 or 5), the scheme start checking convergence by comparing partial results in consecutive steps. In your example, the scheme will need lots of subdivisions to finally see the oscillatory behavior and that is a typical case where false convergence can happen!

How can you integrate an oscillatory function on the open interval `(a,\infinity)`? The explanation of the [qawf integral](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/QAWF-adaptive-integration-for-Fourier-integrals.html#QAWF-adaptive-integration-for-Fourier-integrals) integration scheme is quite complete. Integrate the function on subintervals that contain only a few oscillations and check how the result converge - and then extrapolate that!

There are other numbers that don't quite make sense. Why do you need to sample sin(x)/(1+x^2) at every dx=1e-15? Any reasonable adaptive scheme can integrate sin(x) from 0 to 2Pi w/ ~10-20 sample points.

Simpson's rule did not failed because it is not an adaptive scheme. The python code will determine the 'dx' based on the x-array you provided and it will use that dx all the way to 1e10! However I am pretty sure that roundoff errors are quite bad in your code because you chose dx~1e-15.

EDIT 1 part I: Actually the problem is not only caused by the oscillatory behavior of the integrand. Given that the envelope 1/x^2 converges quite fast - your function is practically zero if x>>1. So, because you are integrating this envelope in the gigantic interval [0,1e10], the adaptive integration thinks the result is quite small because it can't see the small (sub)interval where the function is not negligible. (you may think that the integration routine will distribute the evaluation points uniformly in the close interval [0,1e10] - that is not quite true for gaussian integrals but it is close - so the chance of one of those points to fall inside the interval ~[0,1e3] where the integrand is not negligible is very small. After a few iterations the integration routine will get that your integral is close to zero).

Edit 1 part II: I still think (after reading your comment) the problem is the numbers you plugged (or the python wrapper has a bug.). Please try your example with reasonable numbers as I did in the following C++ code

```
int main()  
{           
  const double omega = 1;
  auto g = [](double x)->double {return 1.0/(1.+x*x);};
  auto f = [&](double x)->double {return std::sin( omega * x) * g(x);};

  const int points_per_cycle  = 20;
  const int n_cycles = 10;
  const int size = n_cycles * points_per_cycle + 1;
  const double xmin = 0.0;
  const double xmax = n_cycles * (2 * M_PI);
  const double L = xmax-xmin;

  std::vector<double> x(size);
  std::vector<double> y(size);

  for (int i = 0; i <size; ++i) {
    x[i] = i * L/(size-1);
    y[i] = f(x[i]);
  }

  std::cout.precision(8); 
  // interpolation
  InterpolationGSL<std::vector<double>> GSLinterpol(x, y, GSLIT::cspline, false);
  // Integral of the interpolation
  std::cout << GSLinterpol.If((1+1e-12)*xmin, (1-1e-12)*xmax) << std::endl;

  // SECOND GSL INTEGRATION
  gsl_integration_workspace* w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000);

  gsl_integration_qawo_table* wf = gsl_integration_qawo_table_alloc 
    (omega, L, GSL_INTEG_SINE, 1000);

  int status = gsl_integration_qawo_table_set (wf, omega, L, GSL_INTEG_SINE);
  if(status) std::cerr<< "error: " << std::string(gsl_strerror (status)) << std::endl;

  double result;
  double abserr;

  std::function<double(double)> gg( std::cref(g) );
  GslFunction Fp(gg); 
  gsl_function *Fgsl = static_cast<gsl_function*>(&Fp);

  status = gsl_integration_qawo (Fgsl, xmin, 0.0, 1e-5, 1000, w, wf, &result, &abserr);

  if(status) std::cerr<< "error: " << std::string(gsl_strerror (status)) << std::endl;
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This code uses my [gsl_function](http://tardis.viniciusmiranda.com:7990/projects/GSL/repos/gslfunction/browse) and [interpolation](http://tardis.viniciusmiranda.com:7990/projects/GSL2/repos/gsldec2014/browse) wrappers - so you may find the code a little strange - but the importante point is that it evaluates the same integral you mentioned on a reasonable interval and the results are

```
Interpolation integral: 0.64631754
GSL integral: 0.64650827
```